# GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails missing buyer's email

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I use PayPal's **Website Payment Pro** with recurring payments.

Some profiles are created using a credit card, others using a PayPal account (user's use their PayPal account to fund the transaction).

I am trying to get the user's email address (if the user used PayPal) via `GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails` API operation. I can see that there is a Email property that comes back, but it's always empty. I assume it will come back with a value only if I initially set something for it.

I see that I can use another operation, `GetExpressCheckoutDetails`, however all I have is the profileId, no the token needed for the `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` request.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a token, ProfileID is enough to make the call.
Please refer to [GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails)

Besides I think ProfileID and token can be used alternatively. ProfileID is received when using credit card and token when using PayPal.